# Laravel Tinker creating new object that have constructer as an interface

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, tinker

I am trying to use Laravel Tinker to create a new object that have a constructer as an interface. 
MyClass.php

```
class MyClass{
 public function __construct(ApiInterface $APIloader)
    {
        $this->APIloader = $APIloader;
    }
}
```

ApiInterface.php

```
interface ApiInterface {
    ..
    ..
}
```

I wanted to test my classes in tinker so what i have done is that:

1. `php artisan tinker`
2. `>> $a = new App\MyClass(new App\ApiInterface);`

The error that i got is :

> PHP Fatal error:  Class 'App\ApiInterface' not found in eval()'d code on line 1

The tinker is not allow me todo that i feel like the tinker does not recognize an interface as a class

Any idea ?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot create an instance of an interface.

If you want to test your code make a dummy class and use that.

```
class TestApi implements ApiInterface {}

$a = new App\MyClass(new App\TestApi);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.interfaces.php

A better alternative than a dummy class is just to use mock objects. They accomplish the same thing procedurally.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/mocking

https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/test-doubles.html

Comment: @trinhdh if this answer helped you, consider accepting it

Comment: Should I put the interface as an argument like that : __construct(ApiInterface $APIloader)

Comment: @ljubadr I will. Stackoverflow is not allow me todo that for now.

Comment: @trinhdh Having the interface as a constructor argument is perfectly valid.